# Error: Failed to lookup view "students/addEdit.hbs" in views directory

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am going to built an application in NodeJS using MongoDB.
But I have an issue while inserting data in the database
please help me why this error occur.

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "students/addEdit.hbs" in views directory "D:\Projects\NodeJS\views"
    at Function.render (D:\Projects\NodeJS\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:580:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (D:\Projects\NodeJS\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at D:\Projects\NodeJS\controllers\studentController.js:8:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Projects\NodeJS\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\Projects\NodeJS\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (D:\Projects\NodeJS\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Projects\NodeJS\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at D:\Projects\NodeJS\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (D:\Projects\NodeJS\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (D:\Projects\NodeJS\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (D:\Projects\NodeJS\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (D:\Projects\NodeJS\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Projects\NodeJS\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (D:\Projects\NodeJS\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at D:\Projects\NodeJS\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (D:\Projects\NodeJS\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
```

[image]

Below is my code for server.js

```
require('./models/db');

const express=require('express');
const path=require('path');
const exphbs=require('express-handlebars');
const bodyparser=require('body-parser');

const studentController=require('./controllers/studentController');
//const stdController=require('/controllers/stdController')

var app=express();
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({
    extended:true
}))

app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'));
app.engine('hbs', exphbs({extname:'hbs', defaultLayout:'mainLayout', layoutsDir: __dirname+'/views/layouts/'}));
app.set('viee engine', 'hbs');

app.listen(4000, ()=>{
    console.log('Express server started at port:4000');

})
app.use('/student', studentController);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's `student/addEdit.hbs`

not `students/addEdit.hbs`